# Regsvr32 problemas con dll y .exe

Tags: c#, vs2017

estoy trabajando en .net  c# y me pasaron unos dll y .exe desarrollados en vb6.
las dll la he registrado por regsvr32 , todo funcionaba ok pero cuando levanto el proyecto después de reiniciar mi pc  me aparece que las dll y los .exe no estuvieran cargados  y cuando los quiero agregar nuevamente  me salen que NO ES UN ELEMENTO .NET

Habra una forma de poder agregarlos nuevamente , como puedo borrar los que ya he registrado por regsvr32 para volver a registrarlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: regsvr32 /u desregistra una dll... pero habria que entender porque algo que registraste despues figura como no registrado...

Comment: eso tmb me parece raro , cuando agrego los .exe se generan los interop pero solo reinicie mi pc y abrí el proyecto,  tenían los dll y  .exe en las referencias , pero me salían los mensajes que sale cuando no agregas una referencia , entonces pensé en quitarlo y agregarlo nuevamente y ya no me deja